# Main thread waits for multiple backgroundworker threads to complete

Tags: c#, multithreading

I spawn multiple backgroundworkerthreads, and want my main thread to wait until all have completed. The solution would be to add an item to the list everytime the backgroundworker thread is spawned and delete them in RunWorkerCompleted. However, how do I pass the list as a parameter into RunWorkerCompleted?

```
FuncA()
{
 foreach()
 {
    /* add an item to the list */
   _bw.RunWorkerAsync();
 }
 m_event.WaitOne(); /* Main thread waits here */
}
static bw_DoWork()
{

}
static bw_RunWorkerCompleted()
{ 
    /* delete item from list */
    /* if list is empty signal m_event.Set() */
}
```

Comment: You don't want to block the main thread.  That will freeze your UI.  Also, incidentally, it will prevent `RunWorkerCompleted` from firing.

Comment: Can you please explain how exactly RunWorkerCompleted wont be fired if main thread is blocked?

Comment: The BGW will marshal the completed event to the main thread, which is unable to then process the request, because it's blocked, until the current request finishes.  It won't finish until the BGW completed event runs.  Deadlock.

Comment: Thanks Servy. Is the deadlock issue only with the background worker thread?

Comment: The deadlock issue is because you're blocking the UI thread.  Don't do that.  You want to not block the UI thread.  If you want to simply do something when all of the background tasks finish (in the UI thread) you can do that.  My answer shows you one way to do that (the easiest, in my opinion).

Answer (score 1):

Using the TPL with `await` makes this *very* easy:

```
private void someEventHandler()
{
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(
        Task.Run(() => ComputeSomeValue()),
        Task.Run(() => ComputeSomeOtherValue()),
        Task.Run(() => ComputeYetAnotherValue()));
    DoSomethingWithResults(results);
}
```

For a .NET 4.0 solution you can use tasks without using `await`:

```
private void someEventHandler()
{
    Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(new[]{
        Task.Run(() => ComputeSomeValue()),
        Task.Run(() => ComputeSomeOtherValue()),
        Task.Run(() => ComputeYetAnotherValue())}
        , resultTask => DoSomethingWithResults(resultTask.Result);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my application runs in .NET framework 4.0 and cannot support TPL :(. I cannot change the framework either due to other dependency constraints. Is there any other work around?

Comment: Sure, there are other ways, although they aren't nearly as nice.  I added one possibility.

Answer (score 0):

When calling _bw.RunWorkerAsync(), you could pass the list as an argument. RunWorkerAsync method has an overload method which takes a type of object as parameter.

You can delete an item from list at the end of bw_DoWork event, rather than in the bw_RunWorkerCompleted event. The latter is supposed to use when updating some UI element.

```
List<object> list = new List<object>();
FuncA()
{
    foreach()
    {
        /* add an item to the list */
       _bw.RunWorkerAsync(list);
     }
    m_event.WaitOne(); /* Main thread waits here */
}
static bw_DoWork()
{
    // Do the stuff.

    /* delete item from list */
    var list = e.Argument as List<object>;
    /* if list is empty signal m_event.Set() */
}
```

Comment: This is then blocking the UI thread for the duration of this long running work, thus freezing the entire UI.  That shouldn't be done; the UI thread should be left to continue processing messages while this work is ongoing.

Answer (score -1):

It you are using .NET Framework 4 or later you can use System.Threading.CountdownEvent for that.
Inside FuncA() before you start your background workers you have to initialize CountdownEvent with a number of your objects and in WorkerCompleted handler you should call  Signal() method of the CountdownEvent.
In the thread which should not continue until all workers will complete you have to call Wait() method of the CountdownEvent and after that method call all you code which must be executed later.

Comment: This will deadlock.  You'll be blocking the UI thread while waiting on the background workers, and the `RunWorkerCompleted` event won't be able to run as it marshals the handler to the UI thread.  Since each is waiting on the other, you get a deadlock.

Comment: @Servy it depends on where you are waiting for the CountdownEvent. It seems clear for me that you should update UI from a separate thread and hence wait for completion in that thread. I wrote not the exact code which needs to be pasted in a project but just an idea how it should be implemented!

Comment: Your answer *specifically* mentions waiting in `FuncA`, which pretty clearly appears to be running in the UI thread.  It's also entirely inappropriate to create a whole new thread just to do nothing but wait for all of these workers to complete.  You don't need a thread at all to do that.

Comment: Really??? "In the thread which should not continue until all workers will complete" - where i am saying Wait should be called inside FuncA()? Who said the thread should do nothing but wait? It is your words, not my.

Comment: The OP is saying he's looking for a way to wait in the main thread.  You're saying that he should use the `CountdowntEvent` to wait in the thread which should not continue, which given the question asked, is the UI thread.  And yes, it is my words that you shouldn't be creating a new thread just so that it can do nothing at all but wait for something else to finish.  It's poor design, wasteful of system resources, and there are much better alternatives.